# How we make text style in android for total layout?

Tags: android

I am new to android application development.

I am developing one small application.In this application one of the xml page i used 3 layouts(Relative,Frame,Relative).

My requirement is i have to apply color and text size styles to all controls in that xml page.

please help me to go forward.

thank you,

bye..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use global theme for the application.
[Apply a theme to an Activity or application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme)